# mortifying Axes objects returned by plt.subplots() with a for loop

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to use for loop to fill each `Axes` in a `subplots` by the following code:

```
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
cols = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']
# plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
for ax_row in range(2):
    for ax_col in range(2):
        for col in cols:
            sns.distplot(df[col], ax=ax[ax_row][ax_col])
```

But I got the same plot in all four axes. How should I change it to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `for col in cols:` where you are looping through all the columns for each subplot. What you instead need is to plot one column at a time in one subplot. To do so, one way is to use an index `i` and keep updating it as you loop through the subplots. Below is the answer:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
cols = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']
# plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(8, 6))
i = 0
for ax_row in range(2):
    for ax_col in range(2):
        ax_ = sns.distplot(df[cols[i]], ax=ax[ax_row][ax_col])
        i += 1
plt.tight_layout()
```

EDIT: Using `enumerate`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(8, 6))
for i, axis in enumerate(ax.flatten()):        
    ax_ = sns.distplot(df[cols[i]], ax=axis)
plt.tight_layout()
```

EDIT 2: Using `enumerate` on `cols`

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(8, 6))
for i, col in enumerate(cols):        
    ax_ = sns.distplot(df[col], ax=axes.flatten()[i])
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: I was assuming that `ax[ax_row][ax_col] = sns.distplot(df[cols[i]])` will do the same thing, but why the plots apper on the axes again. Did I missed something?

Comment: You have an extra for loop

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I'm still struggling with it. I thought you can indexing each axes and assign them to a sns plot... no?

Comment: Remove for col in cols: from your code. This is plotting all 4 columns in each axes subplot

Comment: The only thing I did is changing your code to `ax[ax_row][ax_col] = sns.distplot(df[cols[i]])`I don't  why it is not working.

Comment: You have to assign an axis inside the `distplot` command like I am doing in my answer. What is the problem in using the answer as it is?

Comment: There's no issue. just because sometimes I using axes assignment and so wondering why it is not working...

Comment: is there any way to use `enumerate()`?

Comment: Thanks. Is that possible to the enumerate() the cols list instead?

Comment: What do you mean by enumerating the cols list?

Comment: Ok, check Edit 2